# How would you represent reassignment with a Material UI icon?

Tags: icon, interface-design, google-material-design

Basically look for advice on which icon to use for reassignment of task within the Material UI icons.

Answer (score 1):

[The Noun Project](https://thenounproject.com/term/reassign/) has two great options.

[image]